# Internationalization of a Google Form

Tags: google-forms, localization

I have written a Google Form for my French-language website, with French-written fields.

Problem: All the generic text is still in English, for instance "Required" or "Go back to the form".

Question: How to have those texts be written in French?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change that source URL to read http://spreadsheets.google.com/embeddedform?key=...KEYcode...&hl=fr.
Adding `&hl=fr` is all it takes to  change the language to French.

*BTW: this trick is overruled by the Settings of Google Docs of the client using your form. So problably it seems not to work on your own computer if you are logged in on Google Docs.*

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It seems Google has updated their system.  I get a URL like https://docs.google.com/forms/...CODE.../viewform, and adding `?hl=fr` does nothing to the form.

Answer (score 3):

Change the language setting of your google docs to French (under settings).

I had to do this for my German language form - it works!